# RestKit Post method with JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, restkit

I'm developing an iOS App for school.
I'm using a database so i can run some statistics later.
I created a Restful Web Service to handle all functions I need and using RestKit to access the Web Service.
When I need to retrieve data from WS i dont have any problem to do it, but when i need to post info I am getting some errors that I would like some help if you can.

The POST method I created in WS is for adding a new Collection to DB, it has no return, just add it. I'm using the GSON library to convert from JSON. I tested with the "tester" from netbeans and worked well so I guess the problem is not on the Web Service. I'll put the code for the classes involved and the method that is trying to POST de object.

I have this class: Collection

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "User.h"
@interface Collection : NSObject
@property NSNumber *idCollection;
@property NSString *name;
@property User *user;
@property NSArray *collectionItens;
@end
```

And this class: User

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface User : NSObject
@property NSNumber *idUser;
@property NSString *login;
@property NSString *password;
@end
```

Both class only have the @syntezise

Here is the method im trying to post the object:

```
- (IBAction)createNewCollection:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"..");
Collection *collection = [[Collection alloc] init];
collection.name = collectionNameTextField.text;
collection.user = [AppDefauts defaultUser];

RKObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"idUser", @"login", @"password"]];

RKObjectMapping *collectionMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[collectionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"idCollection", @"name"]];

[collectionMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"user" toKeyPath:@"user" withMapping:userMapping]];



RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:collectionMapping objectClass:[Collection class] rootKeyPath:@"collection" method:RKRequestMethodAny];


RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/MTGAppWS/webresources"]];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

[objectManager postObject:collection path:@"/Collection"    parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Success");

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error");
}];
}
```

Log display on Xcode with error:

http://pastebin.com/JXCYzF8B

Web Service code for include a new Collection

```
@Path("Collection")
public class CollectionService
{
}
@Context
private UriInfo context;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of CollectionService
 */
public CollectionService()
{
}
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
public void createNewCollection(String content)
{
    CollectionController c= new CollectionController(new SQLController());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    parser.parse(content);
    Collection collection = gson.fromJson(content, Collection.class);
    c.criarNovaCollection(collection);

}
```

}

**EDIT**

Found out that the request wasn't "going" to right address.

already fixed that but now its happening another error. (Method not allowed).

Error message: http://pastebin.com/99FiNmQZ

Comment: What is the server expecting to receive? Did you use Charles to see what you're actually sending?

Comment: Sorry but i dont know tha Charles is.
Server is expecting a string that is the json.
I'll post the code that handle this parte.

Comment: Thanks Wain for Charles adivice.
Installed it and i figured that the request was going to wrong address.
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/MTGAppWS/webresources"]]; 

Dont know why but the URL was ignoring the "MTGAppWS/webresources" part.

So when the app requests, the address that the request is going to was "http://192.168.0.200:8080/Collection".

Now i solved it but its now showing a diferente error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server you are communicating with is giving you an HTML error page instead of the JSON you were expecting: `The requested resource () is not available.` The error isn't in your app (unless you are asking for the wrong URL); it's on the server.

Comment: Actually, im not expection a JSON. That method has no return. Not sure if its the best design but its supposed to work. I'll post the code of this part of Web Service. It's writter in Java.